# strtok segmentation fault, another way to split strings?

Tags: c, strtok

Well, I'm having troubles with Strtok. I read many posts saying that I can't use char * with strtok, but, what can else can I use to split a string (char*)? or do you know some way to use strtok with pointers?

```
int play(char** matrixGame, char** matrixUser, int rows, int columns, char* input)
{
   char * token2;
   int x,y;
   char * inputPlay;

   inputPlay = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char)*10);

   token2 = strtok(input, " ");
   x = atoi(token2);

   token2 = strtok(NULL, " ");
   y = atoi(token2);

   token2 = strtok(NULL, " ");
   strcpy(inputPlay,token2);    
}
```

hope you can help me guys, thanks.

Comment: According to [strtok document](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strtok/), it can and will return `NULL` when there is no more token to be found.  So your code has to check for this condition.

Comment: What is `inputAux` in your code here?  Is that a typo?

Comment: @informaton oh nothing, i was trying something and forgot to change it

Comment: @SSC i'll try that, thanks :)

Comment: `token2 = strtok(inputPlay, " ");` --> `token2 = strtok(input, " ");` ?

Comment: @BLUEPIXY yes, is that. i was trying something, but i failed and forgot to change it hahaha (i edited the code now, thanks)

Comment: I would suggest running your code with a debugger like valgrind. That will tell you which call is seg faulting, as it is not clear to at which point the error occurs. It could be that one of the calls to strtok is returning a NULL or maybe the call to strcpy at the end has too small of a buffer.

Comment: @TonyRuth well, i'm debugging with prints and it get down here:
token2 = strtok(NULL, " ");
y = atoi(token2);
//Here.

Comment: Have you printed, the input string and the tokens which have come out of the tokenizer?

Comment: @TonyRuth i tried to print printf("%s", token2) and the same happens.

Comment: @GustavoHurtado, I would suggest printing every token which has come out including the first one. My guess is that the first call to strtok is using up the entire string, and so the second call is receiving a NULL from strtok. You could try putting `if (token2 ==NULL) printf("Null token\n");`

Comment: "I read many posts saying that I can't use `char *` with `strtok()`"-- not quite sure what you mean by this. `strtok()` takes a `char *` that points to the string to be tokenized as an argument. You can't use a pointer to a string literal here, though, since attempts to modify string literals cause undefined behavior, and `strtok()` modifies the input string. Maybe this is what you have read....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These answer addresses OP's question `strtok segmentation fault, another way to split strings?`

Also there is another function called `strsep` but which is not standardized. Based on your use, you can use it too. (At the cost of portability).

You can write your own version of `strtok` throwing away the things you don't like about `strtok`.

You can have a good look at this [discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/673912/developed-a-strtok-alternative) over this thread discussed earlier. The problems like changing the first argument or not working on constant char arrays can be solvable if you implement them for your purpose.

Comment: The idea is to not use char[], that's my problem. But thanks anyways

Comment: @GustavoHurtado.: Ah I can modify the answer if you like. OR you solved it?

Answer (score 0):

I discovered what was happening. I used input before in another function that use strtok too, and i thinked that input was some string like 2 2 x, but strtok modified my input and it was just a 2, not the complete string. So, don't use the same variable.
Many thanks guys.